# Error "cursor X does not exist" when running a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

When running a SQL Stored Procedure, I get this error:

```
cursor with the name 'V_OPEN_INV_REC' does not exist
```

Please, can any one help me?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HRI_FIFO_WITH_ASSIGNED_TO_INV]
        @USERID             INT,
        @CUSTOMERID         INT,
        @ZONEID             INT,
        @SUBCUSTOMER        VARCHAR(20),
        @OK_TO_PROCEED      INT
AS 
    BEGIN


        SET @OK_TO_PROCEED = 1;

        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_PART                           VARCHAR (50)  
        SET @V_CURRENT_PART = '' 

        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_LOT                            VARCHAR (50)  
        SET @V_CURRENT_LOT = '' 

        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_SERIAL                         VARCHAR (50)  
        SET @V_CURRENT_SERIAL = '' 

        DECLARE @V_WITH_CF_QTY                            INT
        DECLARE @V_INVENTORY_METHOD                       VARCHAR (50)
        DECLARE @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY                INT 
        DECLARE @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER                  INT 
        DECLARE @V_QTY_UNASGN_ON_THIS_LAYER               INT 
        DECLARE @V_WATCHES_PROCESSED                      INT 
        DECLARE @IMT_RULE                                 VARCHAR (50) 

        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_DATE                           DATETIME 
        SET @V_CURRENT_DATE=GETDATE()

        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_END_USE                        VARCHAR (50) 
        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_QUALITY                        VARCHAR (50) 
        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_SIZE                           INT
        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_GENDER                         VARCHAR (50) 
        DECLARE @END_USE_RULE                             VARCHAR (50) 
        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG                      VARCHAR (50) 
        DECLARE @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE                        VARCHAR (50) 
        DECLARE @BYPASS_WATCH_AUDIT                       VARCHAR (50) 


        SET @IMT_RULE  = DBO.EZFTZ_HRI_IMT_RULE('Withdraw from Previous Layers Only',@ZONEID,@CUSTOMERID)
        SET @END_USE_RULE  = DBO.EZFTZ_HRI_IMT_RULE('Handle End-Use Processing',@ZONEID,@CUSTOMERID)
        SET @BYPASS_WATCH_AUDIT  = DBO.EZFTZ_HRI_IMT_RULE('Bypass Watch Breakout Audit', @ZONEID,@CUSTOMERID)
        SET @V_WATCHES_PROCESSED  = DBO.EZFTZ_Fn_HAS_WATCH_PARTS(@ZONEID, @CUSTOMERID)


        SET @V_INVENTORY_METHOD  = (SELECT ISNULL(InventoryMethod,'FIFO')   FROM  EZFTZ_tbl_CustomerInfo    WHERE   CustomerID = @CUSTOMERID    AND ZoneNumber=@ZONEID)


        DECLARE @PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @LOT VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @WITHDRAWAL_ID INT
        DECLARE @UNASSIGNED_QTY INT
        DECLARE @SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @ENFORCE_SERIAL_MATCH INT
        DECLARE @WITH_CF_QTY INT
        DECLARE @WITHDRAWAL_DT DATETIME
        DECLARE @END_USE VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @QUALITY VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @SIZE_CODE INT
        DECLARE @GENDER_CODE  VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @FED_SPI VARCHAR(20)
        DECLARE @WITHDRAWAL_TYPE VARCHAR(20)
        DECLARE @ORIG_PRODUCT VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @FTZ_WITH_ID INT
        DECLARE @ENTRY_NO INT
        DECLARE @LAYER_ID INT   
        DECLARE @UNASGN_QTY INT

        DECLARE @RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER INT




        DECLARE GET_REMOVAL_CONFIGS_WITH_INV  CURSOR LOCAL FOR      
        SELECT RC.PROD_CD PRODUCT_ID,
        RC.LOT_NUMBER LOT, 
        RC.FTZ_WITH_CF_ID WITHDRAWAL_ID, 
        RC.WITH_CF_UNASGN_QTY UNASSIGNED_QTY, 
        RC.SERIAL_NUMBER, 
        RC.ENFORCE_SERIAL_MATCH, 
        RC.WITH_CF_QTY, 
        R.WITHDRAWAL_DT, 
        RC.END_USE, 
        RC.QUALITY, 
        RC.SIZE_CODE, 
        RC.GENDER_CODE, 
        RC.FED_SPI, 
        R.WITHDRAWAL_TYPE,
        R.PROD_CD ORIG_PRODUCT, 
        R.FTZ_WITH_ID, 
        R.ENTRY_NO  FROM EZFTZ_tbl_Wdt_Removal_Config RC
        INNER JOIN EZFTZ_tbl_Wdt_Removal R ON RC.ZONE_ID = R.ZONE_ID AND RC.CUSTOMER_ID = R.CUSTOMER_ID AND RC.FTZ_WITH_ID = R.FTZ_WITH_ID 
        WHERE ISNULL(RC.WITH_CF_UNASGN_QTY,0) > 0 
        AND ( RC.WITH_CF_STATUS = 'NEW' OR RC.WITH_CF_STATUS = 'UNFIL' )    
        AND RC.CUSTOMER_ID=@CUSTOMERID AND RC.ZONE_ID=@ZONEID   
        ORDER BY RC.PROD_CD , RC.WITH_CF_BOM_EFF_DT, R.WITHDRAWAL_DT , RC.FTZ_WITH_CF_ID

        OPEN GET_REMOVAL_CONFIGS_WITH_INV       

        FETCH NEXT FROM  GET_REMOVAL_CONFIGS_WITH_INV INTO @PRODUCT_ID,@LOT, @WITHDRAWAL_ID, @UNASSIGNED_QTY, @SERIAL_NUMBER, @ENFORCE_SERIAL_MATCH, @WITH_CF_QTY, @WITHDRAWAL_DT, 
        @END_USE,@QUALITY, @SIZE_CODE, @GENDER_CODE, @FED_SPI, @WITHDRAWAL_TYPE, @ORIG_PRODUCT, @FTZ_WITH_ID, @ENTRY_NO

        ---OPEN V_OPEN_INV_REC
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
            BEGIN           

                SET @V_WITH_CF_QTY  =    @WITH_CF_QTY 

                SET @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  =    @UNASSIGNED_QTY 

                IF @V_CURRENT_PART !=  @PRODUCT_ID OR @V_CURRENT_PART IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_LOT !=    @LOT OR @V_CURRENT_LOT IS NULL 
                OR @V_CURRENT_SERIAL !=    @SERIAL_NUMBER OR @V_CURRENT_SERIAL IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_DATE !=    @WITHDRAWAL_DT OR @V_CURRENT_DATE IS NULL 
                OR @V_CURRENT_END_USE IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_END_USE !=    @END_USE OR @V_CURRENT_QUALITY IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_QUALITY !=    @QUALITY 
                OR @V_CURRENT_SIZE IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_SIZE !=    @SIZE_CODE OR @V_CURRENT_GENDER IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_GENDER !=    @GENDER_CODE 
                OR @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG !=    @ORIG_PRODUCT OR @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE IS NULL OR @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE != @WITHDRAWAL_TYPE 
                BEGIN           
                    SET @V_CURRENT_PART     =    @PRODUCT_ID 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_LOT      =    @LOT 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_SERIAL   =    @SERIAL_NUMBER 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_DATE     =    @WITHDRAWAL_DT 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_END_USE  =    @END_USE 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_QUALITY  =    @QUALITY 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_SIZE     =    @SIZE_CODE 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_GENDER   =    @GENDER_CODE 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG=    @ORIG_PRODUCT 
                    SET @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE  =    @WITHDRAWAL_TYPE






                    DECLARE V_OPEN_INV_REC CURSOR LOCAL FOR                     
                    SELECT LAYER_ID,QTY_REMAINING RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER,UNASGN_QTY    FROM EZFTZ_tbl_Inventory_Layer 
                    WHERE COMPONENT_PART_NO = @V_CURRENT_PART 
                    AND ZONE_ID= @ZONEID 
                    AND CUSTOMERID = @CUSTOMERID            
                    AND SERIAL_NUMBER = @V_CURRENT_SERIAL 
                    AND QTY_REMAINING > 0 
                    AND CF214_RELEASED_BY_CUSTOMS != 0 
                    AND ( CONVERT(DATE,RECEIPT_DATE,101) <= CONVERT(DATE,@V_CURRENT_DATE,101) OR @IMT_RULE = 'NO' ) 
                    AND ( @END_USE_RULE = 'NO' OR ( END_USE = @V_CURRENT_END_USE   AND QUALITY = @V_CURRENT_QUALITY AND SIZE_CODE = @V_CURRENT_SIZE AND GENDER_CODE = @V_CURRENT_GENDER ) ) 
                    AND ( ZONE_STATUS != 'Z' OR ( @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE != 'CF7501' AND @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG = @V_CURRENT_PART ) )
                    ORDER BY RECEIPT_DATE ASC, LAYER_ID ASC





                    OPEN V_OPEN_INV_REC 


                    FETCH NEXT FROM V_OPEN_INV_REC INTO @LAYER_ID,@RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER,@UNASGN_QTY 

                    IF NOT (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) 
                        BEGIN 
                            SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = 0 
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN 
                            SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  =   @RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER 
                        END

                        SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = DBO.EZFTZ_Fn_GET_QTY_REM_FOR_LAYER( 1, @V_INVENTORY_METHOD, @V_CURRENT_PART, @ZONEID, @CUSTOMERID, @SUBCUSTOMER, @V_CURRENT_SERIAL, @V_CURRENT_DATE, @IMT_RULE, @V_CURRENT_END_USE, @V_CURRENT_QUALITY, @V_CURRENT_SIZE, @V_CURRENT_GENDER, @END_USE_RULE, @V_CURRENT_LOT, @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG, @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE)

                END



            WHILE  ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0) < @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY AND ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0) > 0 AND @OK_TO_PROCEED = 1
            BEGIN  --(

                    IF ABS(ISNULL(@V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY,0) - ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0))< ISNULL(@V_WITH_CF_QTY,0) * 0.0000001 OR  ABS(ISNULL(@V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY,0) - ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0))< 0.0000000001 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  = @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER 
                    END

                    IF ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0) < ISNULL(@V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY,0) 
                    BEGIN 

                        EXEC EZFTZ_Wdt_HRI_FIFO_CREATE_RL  @WITHDRAWAL_ID,@LAYER_ID,@FTZ_WITH_ID,@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,@PRODUCT_ID,@USERID,@CUSTOMERID,@SUBCUSTOMER,@V_CURRENT_END_USE,@V_CURRENT_QUALITY,@V_CURRENT_GENDER,@V_CURRENT_SIZE,@FED_SPI,@ZONEID,@OK_TO_PROCEED  ,     @ENTRY_NO  ,     @WITHDRAWAL_DT 


                        IF @V_WATCHES_PROCESSED = 1 
                        BEGIN                       
                            EXEC EZFTZ_Wdt_HRI_FIFO_CREATE_WATCH_RL @USERID , @WITHDRAWAL_ID, @LAYER_ID, @BYPASS_WATCH_AUDIT,@ZONEID,@CUSTOMERID,@SUBCUSTOMER ,@OK_TO_PROCEED 
                        END 

                        SET @LAYER_ID=ISNULL(@LAYER_ID,0)



                        UPDATE  EZFTZ_tbl_Inventory_Layer   SET QTY_REMAINING = 0,UNASGN_QTY = 0,LAST_WD_DATE = DBO.EZFTZ_fn_Com_GET_LAST_DATE(LAST_WD_DATE, @WITHDRAWAL_DT) 
                        WHERE  LAYER_ID  = @LAYER_ID AND ZONE_ID=@ZONEID AND CUSTOMERID=@CUSTOMERID

                        SET @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  = ISNULL(@V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY,0) - @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER 

                        UPDATE  EZFTZ_tbl_Wdt_Removal_Config  SET   WITH_CF_UNASGN_QTY = @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY,MFG_UNASGN_QTY = @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY 
                        WHERE  FTZ_WITH_CF_ID  = @WITHDRAWAL_ID AND ZONE_ID=@ZONEID AND CUSTOMER_ID=@CUSTOMERID 


                         SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = DBO.EZFTZ_Fn_GET_QTY_REM_FOR_LAYER( 0, @V_INVENTORY_METHOD, @V_CURRENT_PART, @ZONEID, @CUSTOMERID, @SUBCUSTOMER, @V_CURRENT_SERIAL, @V_CURRENT_DATE, @IMT_RULE, @V_CURRENT_END_USE, @V_CURRENT_QUALITY, @V_CURRENT_SIZE, @V_CURRENT_GENDER, @END_USE_RULE, @V_CURRENT_LOT, @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG, @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE)



                        FETCH NEXT FROM V_OPEN_INV_REC INTO @LAYER_ID,@RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER,@UNASGN_QTY 


                        IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = -1) 
                            BEGIN 
                                SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = 0                                           
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN 
                                SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  =   @RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER 
                            END

                    END
                END             

                IF @OK_TO_PROCEED = 1 
                BEGIN 
                    IF ABS(@V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY - @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER)< @V_WITH_CF_QTY * 0.0000001 OR ABS(@V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY - @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER)< .0000000001
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  = @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER 
                    END

                    IF ( ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0) = 0 ) 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  = 0 
                        CLOSE V_OPEN_INV_REC
                        DEALLOCATE V_OPEN_INV_REC
                    END 
                ELSE
                    BEGIN 

                        EXEC EZFTZ_Wdt_HRI_FIFO_CREATE_RL    @WITHDRAWAL_ID  ,     @LAYER_ID  ,  @FTZ_WITH_ID  ,  @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  , @PRODUCT_ID  ,  @USERID  ,  @CUSTOMERID  ,  @SUBCUSTOMER  ,  @V_CURRENT_END_USE  ,  @V_CURRENT_QUALITY  ,  @V_CURRENT_GENDER  ,  @V_CURRENT_SIZE  ,     @FED_SPI  ,@ZONEID,  @OK_TO_PROCEED  ,     @ENTRY_NO  ,     @WITHDRAWAL_DT 

                        IF @V_WATCHES_PROCESSED = 1 
                        BEGIN
                            EXEC EZFTZ_WDT_HRI_FIFO_CREATE_WATCH_RL @USERID , @WITHDRAWAL_ID , @LAYER_ID , @BYPASS_WATCH_AUDIT ,@ZONEID,@CUSTOMERID,@SUBCUSTOMER ,@OK_TO_PROCEED 
                        END         

                        SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER - @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY 

                        SET @V_QTY_UNASGN_ON_THIS_LAYER  =    @UNASGN_QTY 

                        IF ISNULL(@V_QTY_UNASGN_ON_THIS_LAYER,0) > ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0)                      
                        BEGIN   
                             SET @V_QTY_UNASGN_ON_THIS_LAYER  = @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER 
                        END

                        UPDATE  EZFTZ_tbl_Inventory_Layer   
                        SET QTY_REMAINING = DBO.EZFTZ_Fn_Com_HRI_ROUND(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER, 11),   
                        UNASGN_QTY = DBO.EZFTZ_Fn_Com_HRI_ROUND(@V_QTY_UNASGN_ON_THIS_LAYER, 11),   
                        LAST_WD_DATE = DBO.EZFTZ_fn_Com_GET_LAST_DATE(LAST_WD_DATE, @WITHDRAWAL_DT) 
                        WHERE  LAYER_ID  = @LAYER_ID AND ZONE_ID=@ZONEID AND CUSTOMERID=@CUSTOMERID

                        UPDATE  EZFTZ_tbl_Wdt_Removal_Config  SET   WITH_CF_UNASGN_QTY = 0, MFG_UNASGN_QTY = 0 
                        WHERE  FTZ_WITH_CF_ID  = @WITHDRAWAL_ID AND ZONE_ID=@ZONEID AND CUSTOMER_ID=@CUSTOMERID

                        SET @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  = 0 

                        IF ( ISNULL(@V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER,0) = 0 ) 
                        BEGIN 
                            SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = DBO.EZFTZ_Fn_GET_QTY_REM_FOR_LAYER( 0, @V_INVENTORY_METHOD, @V_CURRENT_PART, @ZONEID, @CUSTOMERID, @SUBCUSTOMER, @V_CURRENT_SERIAL, @V_CURRENT_DATE, @IMT_RULE, @V_CURRENT_END_USE, @V_CURRENT_QUALITY, @V_CURRENT_SIZE, @V_CURRENT_GENDER, @END_USE_RULE, @V_CURRENT_LOT, @V_CURRENT_PART_ORIG, @V_CURRENT_WD_TYPE)
                        END


                        IF ( @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER = 0 ) 
                        BEGIN               
                           FETCH NEXT FROM V_OPEN_INV_REC INTO @LAYER_ID,@RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER,@UNASGN_QTY 

                            IF ( (@@FETCH_STATUS = -1) ) 
                                BEGIN
                                    SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  = 0 
                                END 
                            ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                    SET @V_QTY_REM_ON_THIS_LAYER  =   @RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER 
                                END

                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            CLOSE V_OPEN_INV_REC
                            DEALLOCATE V_OPEN_INV_REC                       
                        END


                    END


                END 

                FETCH NEXT FROM  GET_REMOVAL_CONFIGS_WITH_INV INTO @PRODUCT_ID,@LOT, @WITHDRAWAL_ID, @UNASSIGNED_QTY, @SERIAL_NUMBER, @ENFORCE_SERIAL_MATCH, @WITH_CF_QTY, @WITHDRAWAL_DT, 
                @END_USE,@QUALITY, @SIZE_CODE, @GENDER_CODE, @FED_SPI, @WITHDRAWAL_TYPE, @ORIG_PRODUCT, @FTZ_WITH_ID, @ENTRY_NO

                END

            CLOSE GET_REMOVAL_CONFIGS_WITH_INV
            DEALLOCATE GET_REMOVAL_CONFIGS_WITH_INV



        SET @OK_TO_PROCEED = 1
END
```

Comment: Please update your title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but it appears that about 2/3 of the way down you close the cursor and then try to use it again without reopening it. Apologies if I've missed something - there is a lot of code there!

```
CLOSE V_OPEN_INV_REC
                    DEALLOCATE V_OPEN_INV_REC
                END 
            ELSE
                BEGIN 

                    EXEC EZFTZ_Wdt_HRI_FIFO_CREATE_RL    @WITHDRAWAL_ID  ,     @LAYER_ID  ,  @FTZ_WITH_ID  ,  @V_UNSATISFIED_REMOVAL_QTY  , @PRODUCT_ID  ,  @USERID  ,  @CUSTOMERID  ,  @SUBCUSTOMER  ,  @V_CURRENT_END_USE  ,  @V_CURRENT_QUALITY  ,  @V_CURRENT_GENDER  ,  @V_CURRENT_SIZE  ,     @FED_SPI  ,@ZONEID,  @OK_TO_PROCEED  ,     @ENTRY_NO  ,     @WITHDRAWAL_DT 

                    IF @V_WATCHES_PROCESSED = 1 
                    BEGIN
```

So you've closed it and then try to use it again later.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM V_OPEN_INV_REC INTO @LAYER_ID,@RMN_QTY_ON_LAYER,@UNASGN_QTY
```

Comment: Yes I tried lot of way but still i got same error witch place correctly i close that my problem...

Comment: Sorry, so are you saying it is still a problem or it is fixed?